# inserir comandos bash no expect

Tags: variáveis, bash, shell-script, smtp

Boa noite pessoal, tenho uma atividade para fazer que foi preciso que eu utilizasse o Expect para retirar a interação do usuario em uma comunicação SMTP. So que no corpo do e-mail preciso adicionar a data corrente e o tamanho de um arquivo. o código esta assim

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
puts "Enviando e-mail para Administrador!!"
spawn telnet 192.168.0.102 25
expect "%"
send "helo script.com.br\r"
expect "%"
send "mail from: gerente@script.com.br\r"
expect "%"
send"rcpt to: admin@script.com.br\r"
expect "%"
send "data\r"
expect "%"
send "Backup concluido com sucesso\r"
send ".\r"
expect "%"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
```

mas já eu gostaria que ele recebesse esse comando aqui mas não sei como faço

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
DATA=$(date)
TAMARQ=$(ls -l | grep "arquivo_bakcup" | awk '{print $5}')
puts "Enviando e-mail para Administrador!!"
spawn telnet 192.168.0.102 25
expect "%"
send "helo script.com.br\r"
expect "%"
send "mail from: gerente@script.com.br\r"
expect "%"
send"rcpt to: admin@script.com.br\r"
expect "%"
send "data\r"
expect "%"
send "Backup concluido com sucesso\r"
send "$DATA Tamanho do arquivo de backup: $TAMARQ\r"
send ".\r"
expect "%"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
```

tentei usar os comando com spawn mas ele não aceita no email, não sei como dar continuidade dai, e também não pode os dados ser passados por parâmetro pois eu preciso que esse script seja agendado e que execute sozinho.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar argumentos na chamada do script.

Exemplo copiado do Stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059682/how-to-pass-argument-in-expect-through-command-line-in-shell-script

---

Script:

```
set username [lindex $argv 0];
set password [lindex $argv 1];
send_user "$username $password"
```

Chamada do script

```
$ ./test.exp user1 pass1
user1 pass1
```

---

Obs.: não conheço expect, e não testei a solução proposta.